# OpenGL weird results when applying normals to quads

Tags: opengl, lighting, normals

I'm having an issue with ligthing on my white walls, as you can see:

[image]

The following is the code I use to produce a piece of wall, I used these to make the whole building. I just made a cube for simpler coordinates, added normals and then scaled it in two possible ways according to where I wanted to use it. Here is the code

```
    private static void wallUnit(GLAutoDrawable glAutoDrawable, int param) {
    GL2 gl2 = glAutoDrawable.getGL().getGL2();

    gl2.glBindTexture(gl2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1);

    if (param == 0)
        gl2.glScalef(0.5f, 3f, 6f); // side wall
    else
        gl2.glScalef(6f, 3f, 0.5f); // front/ back walls

    gl2.glBegin(gl2.GL_QUADS);    

    // Back face
    gl2.glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f); // quad normal
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(2.0f, 0.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); 
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(2.0f, 2.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1f, -1.0f);  
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 2.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1f, -1.0f);        

    // Bottom face
    gl2.glNormal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // quad normal
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(2.0f, 0.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); 
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(2.0f, 2.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);   
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 2.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);        

    // Right side
    gl2.glNormal3f(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // quad normal
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(2.0f, 0.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);    
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(2.0f, 2.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);     
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 2.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1f, -1.0f);         

    // Top face
    gl2.glNormal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // quad normal
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(2.0f, 0.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1f, -1.0f);   
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(2.0f, 2.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1f, -1.0f); 
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 2.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1f, 1.0f);        

    // Left side
    gl2.glNormal3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // quad normal
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);  
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(2.0f, 0.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);    
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(2.0f, 2.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);     
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 2.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1f, -1.0f);        

    // Front face
    gl2.glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // quad normal
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(2.0f, 0.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);  
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(2.0f, 2.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1f, 1.0f);
    gl2.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 2.0f);
    gl2.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1f, 1.0f);        

    gl2.glEnd();
}
```

Now as you can see there is a problem where two pieces of wall next to one another have the same normals and so are supposed to be the same colour, right? But instead one part of the wall is just darker. What went wrong?

Comment: Can you try adding a `glEnable(GL_RESCALE_NORMAL)` in your setup code? Since you have a scaling transformation, your normals will get scaled along with the positions.

Comment: Awesome, that was what I needed. I wasn't aware that the norms would get scaled as well.

Answer (score 0):

With the legacy fixed pipeline, your current model-view transformation is applied to your normals. Or more precisely, the inverse-transpose of the top-left 3x3 sub-matrix of the model-view transformation is applied to the normals. Which is what's needed for correctly applying the same transformation to the normal vectors.

The one thing you need to watch out for is that the normals might not be normalized anymore after this transformation is applied. By default, they are **not** automatically renormalized. The typical symptom of non-normalized normals is wrong lighting calculations, as you're seeing in your example.

As long as your model-view transformation only consists of rotations and translations, you have nothing to worry about. Rotations do not change the length of a vector, and the translation part is not even applied to the normals. However, if any other types of transformations are part of the model-view matrix, the normals have to be re-normalized after transformation.

There are two options to force re-normalization of the normals after transformation. If, in addition to rotations and translations, your model-view matrix only contains **uniform scaling**, you can use:

```
glEnable(GL_RESCALE_NORMAL);
```

This can be more efficient than the more general option:

```
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
```

This will perform a full re-normalization of the normal, which works for any type of transformation. Typical types of transformations where this option is needed are non-uniform scaling, or shear transforms.